# Digit Factors in a number

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Given a number `n`, design an algorithm and
write the Python program to print the digits of
`n` that divides `n`. Print the digits in reverse
order of their appearance in the number 'n'

For example, if `n` is `122` then print `2, 2, 1`. Use
only conditional and iterative statements to
write the code.

If none of the digits divide the
number, then print 'No factors'

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Coud you please share your code an explain what's the problem with it?

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are searching for

```py
def ex(n):
    flag = True
    n_string = str(n)[::-1]
    for i in n_string:
        if i != '0':
            if n % int(i):
                flag = False
                print(i)
    if flag:
        print ('No factors')
```

Comment: Please have a look at the section about answering in https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 0):

```
n = input()
lst = []

for i in n :

    if int(n) % int(i) == 0 :
        lst.append(i)

if len(lst) == 0 :
    print("No factors")
else :
    lst1 = lst[::-1]
    for i in lst1 :
        print(i)
```

Comment: Hello, Please refrain from posing raw code snippets as answers. Please add at least *some* explanation